# Data modeling with AppEngine python and Queries with 'IN' range

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a list of addresses as string type and I'd like find all events whose location value matches the contents of the list. Because I have thousands of such entries, using the 'IN' with a filter won't work as I've exceeded the limit of 30 items/fetch.

Here's how I'm trying to do a filter:

```
# addresses come in as list of string items
addresses = ['123 Main St, Portland, ME', '500 Broadway, New York, NY', ...];

query = Event.all();
query.filter('location IN ', addresses);
# above causes the error: 
<class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadArgumentError'>:
Cannot satisfy query -- too many subqueries (max: 30, got 119). 
Probable cause: too many IN/!= filters in query.
```

My model classes:

```
class Event(GeoModel):
  name = db.StringProperty();
  location = db.PostalAddressProperty();
```

Is there a better way to find all entries that match a specific criteria?

Comment: How many total entities do you have in the datastore. It might almost make sense to do the filtering in memory, or, if the list of addresses to match is the same all the time, to do a map-reduce job to set a boolean property in the entities showing whether the entity matches the address list.  The IN query itself actually does 30 queries behind the scenes anyway; there's no way to do a query like this efficiently.

Comment: Total entries is dynamic - could be few, could be a lot. In the range of 100 - 10k. Perhaps map reduce is a good option for this task.

Comment: @DanHolman depending on your use case, Map Reduce seems like a good fit. Remember that a IN query is actually running 1 query per parameter (thus, the 30 elements limit), which is not only slow but also has a huge impact on quota usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way around this other than multiple queries - you are, after all, asking for the combined results of a set of queries for different addresses, and this is how 'IN' queries are implemented in the datastore. You might want to consider using ndb or asynchronous queries so you can run them in parallel.

Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to achieve, we can suggest a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution/(hack) would be to break up your list of addresses to lists of 30 each. Do 1 query per 30 locations then take an intersection of the query results to get the events in every location in the original list.

Comment: that's what I'm doing but I wondered if there's a better way.

Answer (score -1):

GQL ‘IN’ does not allow sub-queries more than 30. For this purpose, I have divided sub queries into small chunks for less than or equal 30 sub-queries and result stored into an array.

```
 resultArray = []
 rLength = 0.0
 rCount = len(subQueryArray)
 rLength = len(subQueryArray)/29.0
 arrayLength = int(math.ceil( rLength ))
 # If subqueries are greater than 30 than divide sub-query length by 29 or 30
 if arrayLength > 1:
     for ii in range (0, arrayLength):
 #srange = start range, nrange = new range
 if ii == 0:
     srange = ii
 else:
     srange = nrange + 1
 nrange = 29 * (ii + 1)
 newList = []
 for nii in range (srange, nrange+1):
 if nii < rCount:
     newList.append(subQueryArray[nii])
     query = db.GqlQuery(“SELECT * FROM table_name ” +“WHERE req_id in:1”,newList)
 for result in query.run():
 # result.id belongs to table entity
 resultArray.append(result.id)
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, the way you posted it, this code is barely usable.